# MySQL error no. 1064 query runs correctly without procedure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Proc_UpdEmployeeDetails`( OUT userid integer, IN sal INTEGER)
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET salary=sal
    WHERE id = userid;
END
```

Comment: if you are taking arguments as input parameter then you don't need to specify IN or out

Comment: Praveen: Welcome to SO, but it is currently unclear what you are asking or what problem you are facing. Can you please try giving more details and background? Checkout this handy guide for tips http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you want both input parameters to be labelled as `IN`, assuming you just want to update the `employee` table without returning a value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Proc_UpdEmployeeDetails`(IN userid integer, IN sal INTEGER)
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET salary=sal
    WHERE id = userid;
END
```